# Unexpected behavior from shell script's ln -sfn -v

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have the following:

```
if [ $kernel == 'Darwin' ]; then
    $HOME="/Users/$user"
elif [ $kernel == 'Linux' ]; then
    $HOME="/home/$user"
fi

# Let the script know what the dotfiles dir is
dotfiles_dir="$HOME/dotfiles"

# Making symlinks to shell files, add yours as you need
echo 'Making symlinks to shell files'
ln -sfn -v $dotfiles_dir/shells/zsh $HOME/.zsh
ln -sfn -v $dotfiles_dir/shells/zsh/zshrc $HOME/.zshrc
ln -sfn -v $dotfiles_dir/shells/bash $HOME/.bash
ln -sfn -v $dotfiles_dir/shells/bash/bash_profile $HOME/.bash_profile
ln -sfn -v $dotfiles_dir/shells/bash/bashrc $HOME/.bashrc
ln -sfn -v $dotfiles_dir/shells/profile $HOME/.profile
echo "Done at [$time]...\n"
```

However, this strangely outputs:

```
[Other output here...]

Making symlinks shell files
/Users/eduan/.zsh -> /Users/eduan/dotfiles/shells/zsh
/Users/eduan/.zshrc -> /Users/eduan/dotfiles/shells/zsh/zshrc
/Users/eduan/.bash -> /Users/eduan/dotfiles/shells/bash
./bashrc -> /Users/eduan/dotfiles/shells/bash/bashrc
/Users/eduan/.profile -> /Users/eduan/dotfiles/shells/profile
Done at [08:15]...

[Other output here...]
```

Can anybody tell me why I get this unexpected output? The rest of my symlinks are generated correctly, however the Bash symlinks are messed up for some reason.

BTW, this is in a big script that generates symlinks. This is only part of it, and I put the relevant parts, so that you don't get confused. :)

EDIT:

Here's the link to the latest version of the script: https://github.com/Greduan/dotfiles/blob/master/scripts/make_symlinks.sh

Comment: There are no obvious syntax errors that I can see.  Without being able to duplicate your results, all I can suggest is that there's something you haven't told us yet.  Perhaps is more information that is relevant.

Comment: @ghoti Here's the latest version of the script: https://github.com/Greduan/dotfiles/blob/master/scripts/make_symlinks.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The darwin version of the symlink commands is missing the destination for bashrc, so going to the current directory.

I'm not sure why there are two versions of that bit of the script?

Also you only create the backup directory if it already exists, which can't be right?

Comment: Thanks for answer! That was it! I forgot I had two versions. :P Also, you made me realize I no longer need to separate for Darwin or Linux, since the directories are already set. :)

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong, isn't it. Missing destination directory.

```
ln -sfn -v $dotfiles_dir/shells/bash/bashrc
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for answer! Same thing @Douglas Leeder said, didn't realize it before! :)